# Google Documents List API v3 - How to create a folder?

Tags: google-docs-api

I tried to create a new folder following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only

instead of term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document, I used term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder.

However, I get a HTTP status 200 and no folder is created. Even if I use term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document the result is same.

I saw issues with this method in my search and I tried to post to https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A
Now, I get a 400 error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a folder, send a `POST` request to `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full` with the following xml body:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder"/>
  <title>Example Collection</title>
</entry>
```

For more details, check the specific section in the docs: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_collections